# How to keep emails that I put in my folders while deleting them from my inbox in Gmail

Tags: gmail

How can I keep my messages I put into my folders I created in Gmail? In my Yahoo account, I have lots of folders where I keep receipts, medical records, etc. and they do not appear in my inbox after I transfer them to the folders, but in Gmail the message stays in the inbox and if I delete it from my inbox, it disappears from my folder as well.

How can I keep my messages in the folders and stop them from being in my inbox?

Answer (score 4):

You don’t have to delete anything. If you want to remove them from your inbox, you just need to move them to a folder (the actual action here is applying a label to the respective emails) and then *archive* them. This way, you will still find them under the respective label(s)/folder(s) (and under *All Mail*), but you won’t see them in your general inbox.

To archive them, simply select the ones you want and then click on the **Archive** button next to the select box, at the top of the inbox.

[image]

or

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two concepts that need to be addressed here.

**Moving to a folder** - This removes the email from your main "inbox" and *moves* it into the folder. To access this email, you must either view the specific folder or the "all mail" box.

**Labeling an email** - This applies a label (which are confusingly named the same as your folders) *without* moving the email. It will remain in your inbox.

In reality, "Folders" and "Labels" are really the same thing - with the difference of where you can see the email (the inbox or the "folder"). "Moving" the email automatically removes the "inbox" label from the email so that it will only show up in the other "folders".

It sounds like you are applying labels and not actually moving the email into a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't delete them, the folders is a kind of tag, and you can delete the tag of inbox and it will not be showed on your inbox but will be keep on your folders