# Missing Gmail archive button

Tags: gmail, gmail-archive

There is no archive button when I open Gmail. How can I create an archive and move old emails?

I tried moving old emails to an archive using the `in:` and `before:` but the archive either was not created or the emails did not transfer. They are still in my inbox.

Comment: Have you selected _any_ email? It doesn’t appear unless you select al least one email. See [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/53051/1512) for details.

Comment: Or if you don’t open the email message.

Comment: If I recall, the Archive button only appears when you're looking at the list in the inbox _and_ have one or more messages checked. Try looking under the "More" menu.

Answer (score 1):

Archive in Gmail just means that the inbox label has been removed.

Select an email by opening it or checking it, then one of the buttons at the top of the page will allow you to archive the email.

Archiving works best if you have at least one other label on the message. That means that the message can be found under that label. The strength of Gmail is that a message/conversation can have multiple labels. In other systems a message can only be in one folder, but Gmail allows it to be found under multiple labels. The multiple labels can also be used to zero in on the correct set of messages during search.